# Sending attachments in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, email-attachments

I have been reading through the forums that it is not possible to send attachments through emails in Windows phone. Is this accurate? Is creating a web service my only option?

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Jai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, the current SDK (7.1.1) doesn't allow us to send email messages with attachments; all you can send is text!

The only way is to get the file content (byte array) you want to send, encode it to Base64, and just set the message text to this enconded content...

Comment: @PedroLamas..Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any example code on how to achieve this? Also if you can suggest how I can download the same information that would be really helpful.

Comment: Think I can do better: check [this](http://dennisdel.com/blog/pushing-the-limits-of-the-windows-phone-sdk-ndash-sending-files-via-emailcomposetask) article about how to achieve this!

Comment: The original article blog seems to be missing, but here is a copy of it: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/pushing-limits-windows-phone